# Is it possible to access the QGIS processing-algorithm interfaces (GUI) with python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, qgis-processing

I want to run some python code to access an algorithm in the processing toolbox. The result should be, that the GUI of the Algorithm pops up. (Similar to clicking on an algorithm in the Toolbox itself.)

```
processing.runalg('algorithm & parameters')
```

With this code I can run an algorithm within a script, but this is not what I am looking for. In QGIS 2.18 fTools are gone and replaced by processing-algorithms, but I doubt, that this was done using python. 
So it seems possible, but is it possible with python?

Comment: Oh yes, I was searching for hours and didn't see that.